# View cannot be cast to ViewGroup in fragment with sliding menu

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-view, slidingmenu, android-viewgroup

This Exception occurred in

```
    slidingMenu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.LEFT);
```

line when  I try to show some extra information on Mark click. I want to show the content in sliding menu. "this" object refer to MapActivity class(my custom java class) that extends AppCompatActivity class.
This method is in My MapActivity class which is responsible for initializing sliding menu:

```
private void initSlideMenu(){
    slidingMenu = new SlidingMenu(this);
    slidingMenu.setMode(SlidingMenu.RIGHT);
    double dimension = Master.checkDimension(G.currentActivity);
    Log.i("dimension", dimension + "");
    if (dimension < 4)
        slidingMenu.setBehindOffset(100);
    else if (dimension >= 4 && dimension <= 5)
        slidingMenu.setBehindOffset(300);
    else if (dimension > 5)
        slidingMenu.setBehindOffset(250);
    slidingMenu.setFadeDegree(0.8f);
    slidingMenu.setFadeEnabled(true);
    slidingMenu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.LEFT);
    if (dimension <= 6) {
        slidingMenu.setSlidingEnabled(false);
    }
    View view = G.inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_details, null);
    slidingMenu.setMenu(view);


}
```

and my layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <fragment
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />


</LinearLayout>
```

And My Java class:

```
public class MapActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

GoogleMap googleMap;
MapFragment mMapFragment;
LatLng myLocation;
public boolean firstTime = true;
ArrayList<Double> xList = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Double> yList = new ArrayList<>();
SlidingMenu slidingMenu;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.map_activity);
    MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);

    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

}

@Override
public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap map) {

    Log.i("Position", "SS");
    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    final BitmapDescriptor saharsunLocationIcon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.saharsun_smal);
    final BitmapDescriptor myLocationIcon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED);
    // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
    map.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
            if (marker.getTitle().equals("I'm Hear")) {
                MediaPlayer mPlayer2;
                mPlayer2 = MediaPlayer.create(G.currentActivity, R.raw.cow_sound);
                mPlayer2.start();
                initSlideMenu();
                Log.i("MARKER", marker.getTitle());
            }
            Log.i("MARKER", marker.getTitle());

            return true;
        }
    });
    if (map != null) {

        map.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(new                      GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Random random = new Random();
                myLocation = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),
                        location.getLongitude());

                Log.i("Position", location.getLatitude() + " " + location.getLongitude());
                if (firstTime) {
                    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(myLocation, 16));
                    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(
                            new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude())).title("It's Me!")).setIcon(myLocationIcon);

                    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                        double x = random.nextDouble() / 100 - 0.001 + location.getLatitude();
                        double y = random.nextDouble() / 100 - 0.001 + location.getLongitude();
                        xList.add(x);
                        yList.add(y);
                        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(
                                new LatLng(x, y)).title("I'm Hear")).setIcon(saharsunLocationIcon);

                    }
                    firstTime = false;

                }
            }
        });

    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    G.currentActivity = this;
}
```

and The Logs:

```
08-13 11:44:53.479 19262-19262/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: mahdi.yusefi.qrcodereader, PID: 19262
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.View cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup
    at com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.SlidingMenu.attachToActivity(SlidingMenu.java:318)
    at com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.SlidingMenu.attachToActivity(SlidingMenu.java:292)
    at mahdi.yusefi.qrcodereader.MapActivity.initSlideMenu(MapActivity.java:124)
    at mahdi.yusefi.qrcodereader.MapActivity.access$000(MapActivity.java:26)
    at mahdi.yusefi.qrcodereader.MapActivity$1.onMarkerClick(MapActivity.java:62)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap$10.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.n$a.onTransact(Unknown Source)
    at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:380)
    at yc.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:84)
    at maps.ad.T.b(Unknown Source)
    at maps.D.d.a(Unknown Source)
    at maps.V.k.a(Unknown Source)
    at maps.V.u.d(Unknown Source)
    at maps.V.P.onSingleTapConfirmed(Unknown Source)
    at maps.z.e$b.onSingleTapConfirmed(Unknown Source)
    at maps.z.c$a.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:921)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:716)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

accidentally find the solution.I should init my slide menu in onCreate method. and each time i want to show it  onMarkClick I just call

slidingMenu.toggle();

but still don't have explanation why this exception occurred.